# Searching for a single custom post type, buddypress

Tags: custom-post-types, search, buddypress

I'm trying to show search results only for a specific custom post type, my code is simple and I already tested it successfully on some wordpress sites I made, but in this case (buddypress) looks like it is not working.

Here is my form:

```
<form id="vendor-search" action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>" method="get">
<h5>Search for vendors</h5>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="vendors" />
    <label for="s" class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</label>
    <input type="text" id="s" size="23" name="s" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchsubmit" />
```

So I set this hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="vendors" />
```

and then I get a correct URL when searching, something like:

```
mywebsite.com/?post_type=vendors&s=Marketing
```

but on displayed results it is including all kind of posts and pages...

Any ideas about what can this be?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check out customizing the WP template search.php... you could detect the custom post type query and build your query inside the search.php template as needed.

IF query = custom post type THEN

Customize query using [WP_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

ElSE

Show Standard search results

END IF

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, that might work, let me check on this and get back to you.
Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, I'm trying several ways, but can't get the right code, would you mind to give me a clue of how I should set? I've never customized a search.